# the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script

Tags: perl, cgi

When I run my folder,this error occurs.I want to run localhost/perl/folder name/eample.pl.How to solve it?.Sorry for this easy question.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the server is timing out for some reason. :) 
To get an answer here, you need to be more specific and limit your question to a shot bit of code, you are in doubt about. But check the server's log file for more information. A path may be wrong or a pathname misspelled. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly your `example.pl` CGI program is failing before it has sent a proper response to the browser. Have you tried running it on the command line? You should check the server's error log to see why the program failed

Answer (score 0):

Try running your script on the command line (shell) with options `-cw` - **c** will check the syntax without executing the script, **w** will output warnings.

```
perl -cw localhost/perl/folder\ name/example.pl
```

You should also check the web server's error log file.